# Python - Obtain a full list of product combinations that satisfy a function to be > 0

Tags: python, function, object, product

I have the following two number lists, one an amount and other a probability:

```
stake=[0,2,5,10,20,50,100]
odds=[1,2,5,10,20,50,100]
```

I have created a class 'bet' which takes a certain number of variables and a '.payoff' method which is simply the product of each draw of stake and odds from the above list.

I want to see which combinations of stake and odds satisfy an equation such as below, the sum of different 'bets' multiplied by different combinations of stake and odds

```
def function(stake,odds):
    for s in stake:
        for o in odds:
            bet_all=(bet1.payout(s,o)
            +1*bet2.payout(s,o)
            -2*bet3.payout(s,o)
            +3*bet4.payout(s,o)
            -1*bet5.payout(s,o)
            +1*bet6.payout(s,o))
            
 find (s,o) combinations where bet_all > 0
```

how do i get the full list of stake-odds combinations that yield the sum of each greater than zero?
Above code only results in an error.
Are there any built in packages i could use?

Thanks

---

EDIT

as an example the following random set of s,o combos satisfy the condition in excel:

```
def function(stake,odds):
            bet_all=(bet1.payout(2,5)
            +1*bet2.payout(0,2)
            -2*bet3.payout(2,5)
            +3*bet4.payout(5,10)
            -1*bet5.payout(2,20)
            +1*bet6.payout(5,5))>0
```

problem is i don't know how to print the result out i just get:

```
<function function at 0x000002CAEBD9A1F8>
```

Comment: "Above code only results in an error." What error, where? Looks good to me (except the last line of course). Just collect those `s` and `o` in a list if `bet_all > 0`.

Comment: i posted an example of a random set of s,o combos that satisfy the solution (done in excel) I cant print it out though - how do i make the funciton do it for me?

Comment: its just an example of how it would work for arguments sake

Comment: changed the 3 to a 2 - happy now??

Comment: If `bet1.payout(s,o)` is simply `s*o` (which you seem to indicate) -- why not remove all of those things from your question and simple replace them by the corresponding product? That would be one way to make your question more self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

A naive solution just computes *all* the sums, then filters them.

```
from itertools import product

def bet(s, o):
    return (bet1.payout(s,o)
        +1*bet2.payout(s,o)
        -2*bet3.payout(s,o)
        +3*bet4.payout(s,o)
        -1*bet5.payout(s,o)
        +1*bet6.payout(s,o))

def function(stake, odds):
    return [ x for s, o in product(stake, odds) if (x := bet(s, o)) > 0 ]
```

Comment: If you look at OP's cryptic example, they are computing sums in which *different* `(s,o)` are used in a single sum. It isn't just a product of the two lists, but instead seems more like permutations of the product. But, even that isn't clear since e.g. they use `(3,5)` twice, so maybe they are allowing repeats. I don't think that the question can be answered with the info given.

Comment: True, although the two examples are so different I'm not sure which one should be taken as the actual request.

Comment: I understood that OP wants the actual `s,o` combinations, i.e. `[(s, o) for s, o in ...]`

Comment: correct that i want to allow repeats of combos

Answer (score 0):

This is a brute-force solution for one interpretation of your question. I removed all references to the `payout` method, replacing them with the simple product `s*o`. I also made the weights that you use in the overall sum a parameter to the function.

```
from itertools import product

def positive_bets(weights,stake,odds):
    pairs = product(stake,odds)
    n = len(weights)
    positives = []
    for bets in product(pairs,repeat = n):
        payout = sum(w*b[0]*b[1] for w,b in zip(weights,bets))
        if payout > 0:
            positives.append(bets)
    return positives

#for testing purposes:

weights = [1,1,-2,3,-1,1]
stake=[0,2,5,10]
odds=[1,2,5,10]

test = positive_bets(weights,stake,odds)
print(len(test))
for bets in test[:3]: print(bets)
```

Output:

```
12116129
((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (2, 1))
((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (2, 2))
((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (2, 5))
```

Unfortunately, with your choice of `stake` and `odds`, this code would take much, much longer to run. Brute-force rapidly becomes infeasible.